# Youtube Api PlaylistItems insert error Flutter

Tags: flutter, insert, youtube-api

Problem is that the server says 401 not authorized.
Anyone an idea, how I write a function which inserts videos into a playlist?

```
    final String apiUrl = "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=" +
        ApiKey.API_KEY;

      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signInSilently();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.serverAuthCode,
      );
      print("token  "+googleAuth.idToken);


    final response = await http.post(apiUrl, headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer"+ googleAuth.idToken,
      "Accept": "application/json",

    },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      print("Song was added to playlist");
    }
    else{
      print(response.statusCode);
      print("Failture song wasn't added to playlist");
    }
  }
```

This is what worked for me in the YouTube-Api test window

```
POST https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "PLu55WjdIfjnZznsIY0waSdBFMdmle9Xu2",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10"
    }
  }
}
```

But now my problem is, how do i convert this into a working function

Error which is showing up

```
E/flutter ( 8397): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, Object>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 8397): #0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
E/flutter ( 8397): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 8397): #2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
E/flutter ( 8397): #3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
E/flutter ( 8397): #4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
E/flutter ( 8397): #5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:85:17)
E/flutter ( 8397): #6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter ( 8397): #7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:70:16)
E/flutter ( 8397): #8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:166:20)
E/flutter ( 8397): #9      post (package:http/http.dart:69:5)
E/flutter ( 8397): #10     AdminAddRequestToPlaylist.addVideoToPlaylist (package:flutter_app/screens/admin/conponents/AdminAddRequestsToPlaylist.dart:125:28)
E/flutter ( 8397): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8397):
```

Comment: Inserting a video item into a playlist need you being [properly authenticated/authorized](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert#auth). By no means an API key will work with this API endpoint.

Comment: Well tried to manage this, but always a 401. Even with a Oauth. Do you maybe have a code snippet?

Comment: Look into this official Java sample code: [`PlaylistUpdates.java`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/PlaylistUpdates.java) and [Auth.java](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java).

Comment: thx, but u aint got a dart example right? I'm not the best in converting code between different langugages

Comment: You are using google signin which is open id connect you need Authorization  not authencation.     you need to add one of the YouTube scopes to this or you wont have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `accessToken` and not an `idToken`. Try the code below

```dart
addPlayListItem() async {
    final String apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems";

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn()
        .signInSilently();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser
        .authentication;
    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.serverAuthCode,
    );
    print("token  " + googleAuth.accessToken); // accessToken not idToken


    final response = await http.post(
      apiUrl,
      headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${googleAuth.accessToken}", // Use access token and add a space after the 'Bearer
      "Accept": "application/json",
      },
      body: jsonEncode({
        "playlistId": "PLu55WjdIfjnZznsIY0waSdBFMdmle9Xu2",
        "position": 0,
        "resourceId": {
          "kind": "youtube#video",
          "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10"
        }
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print("Song was added to playlist");
    }
    else {
      print(response.statusCode);
      print("Failture song wasn't added to playlist");
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, well we moved now from a 401 to a 403

Comment: Maybe its cuz of the missing body, cuz if im implementing the body its crashing

Comment: Yes please add the body and your request should be sucessful